# VHDL - determining the range of a 2d array

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

I have two 2D arrays:

```
type array1x1D is array (0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(0 to 10); -- Array of arrays
type array2D is array (0 to 10, 0 to 10) of std_logic; -- Real 2D array
```

How do I access the range of the `std_logic_vectors` in the former and the range in the latter? I could of course use a variable to keep track of their size but I would prefer to avoid that. I am trying to loop over the arrays using `GENERATE` statements.

Comment: is it really `0 downto 10`? It could be `10 downto 0` or `0 to 10`.

Comment: could you please show your code with your generate statements?

Comment: @nio oops, yes it is meant to be `0 to 10`. I have edited the post.

Comment: Using VHDL-2002, if you have got a signal/variable/constant of that type, say `data`, you could use `data(data'LEFT)'RANGE` for the first situation (array of arrays)…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**array1x1D:**

VHDL-2002: A subtype is required for the `std_logic_vector(0 downto 10)` if you
want to get the range of this part, thus splitting the type into:

```
subtype array1x1D_element is std_logic_vector(0 to 10);
type array1x1D is array (0 to 10) of array1x1D_element; -- Array of arrays
```

Then you can do `array1x1D_element'range`.

VHDL-2008: Use the added `'element` attribute (probably for that purpose :-), 
and write `array1x1D'element'range`.

**array2D:**

Access the different dimensions through an index to `'range`, thus
with `array2D'range(1)` and `array2D'range(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
entity test1 is
end entity;
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
architecture a1 of test1 is
    type array1x1D is array (0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(0 to 10); -- Array of arrays
    type array2D is array (0 to 10, 0 to 5) of std_logic; -- Real 2D array
    signal s1 : array1x1D;
begin
    name : process is
    begin
        report "array1x1D(0)'length:" & integer'image(s1(0)'length);
        report "array2D'length(1):" & integer'image(array2D'length(1));
        report "array2D'length(2):" & integer'image(array2D'length(2));
        wait;
    end process name;
end architecture a1;
```

produces:

```
# run -all
# ** Note: array1x1D(0)'length:11
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test1
# ** Note: array2D'length(1):11
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test1
# ** Note: array2D'length(2):6
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test1
#
```

I can't immediately see a way to figure out the length of the vector elements of the 1d array without an intermediate signal/constant/variable of that type...

Comment: How would one assign the std_logic_vector in the real 2D array since using both the indices will just limit us to a single std_logic value and using just one index is not enough

Comment: @quantum231: do you mean `array2d(0,0 to 5) <= "01010"`? I don't have a simulator to hand, but I think that's the syntax...